# Value not displaying in h:inputText

Tags: jquery, css, jsf

I need to display the value which is coming from back-end to the jsf `inputText`. When I am debuffing the front-end I am getting that value in value attribute but it is not been displayed in the `inputText`

Can anybody help me with this issue and one more thing on that `inputText` id I am applying some normal jQuery for hide and show functions

Here for example I am using this input text which has class has starthidden

```
<h:inputText type="date" id="strathidden" styleClass="strathidden form-control" value="#{schedule.lockedStartTime}" style="display:none;">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern=" MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a" />
</h:inputText>
```

and the date time picker as

```
var today = new Date();  

  $(' .strathidden').datetimepicker({
     minDate:today
  });
```

Comment: you need to show minimal relevant code to the problem at hand

Comment: We have this input field   <h:inputText type="date" id="strathidden" 
               styleClass="starthidden form-control"
                value="#{schedule.lockedStartTime}" style="display:none;visibility:visible;">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern=" MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a" />
                </h:inputText>     And i am applying datetimepicker    var today = new Date();  

  jQuery(' .strathidden').datetimepicker({
   
   minDate:today
   
  });

Comment: update the OP not comment the code :)